# ETL data merging techniques, matching data from multiple sources

Tags: sql-server, merge, ssis, etl, data-migration

Good day,
I am wondering if there are any good resources out there that I could read / watch to learn more about matching / merging data from multiple sources (previous search attempts are only bring up products for purchase). Specifically if each source does not have a matching ID.

I am currently working on project that involves importing several lists of source data into a SQL DB from various places. Some of the lists have a primary key ID that makes matching them together easy, but others do not use the same primary key or don't have one at all. I am aware of fuzzy matching logic but am wondering if there are any other data matching techniques out there that are used today to match data.

Each of the lists do contain basic values like name, address, DOB, phone, etc. But understanding that sting values aren't the best option to do matching on is why I am looking for suggestions

Any suggestions would be great, I really appreciate the help
Take care

Comment: SQL Server has Integration Services (SSIS) for that.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your suggestion. I am an avid SSIS user and use it quite often. The merge task in SSIS is a good tool, but doesn't quite do what I need unless I have a specific primary key ID to complete the merge successfully. I am looking for other ETL techniques that might be used when a primary key may or may not be available.
Take care

Comment: Try analyzing the data, then creating a composite PK to alleviate your issue.